# How to set normal vertical alignment using xsim and tasks packages?

Tags: tasks, xsim

MWE

```
\documentclass[13pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[no-files]{xsim}
\usepackage{tasks}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{main-task}{
  \par
  \textit{\GetExerciseName}
  \GetExerciseProperty{counter}.
}
{\par}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/the-counter = \thesection.\arabic{exercise},
  exercise/within = section,
  exercise/name = Exercise,
  exercise/template = main-task,
  solution/template = main-task, 
}
\settasks{
  label-format = \bfseries,
  before-skip = -\parskip,
  after-skip = -\parskip,
  after-item-skip = -\parskip
}

\begin{document}

This is a simple text before exercise.This is a simple text before exercise.This is a simple text before exercise.This is a simple text before exercise.This is a simple text before exercise.

\begin{exercise}
    This is a simple text for exercise.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
    This is a simple text for exercise.
    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task This is a simple text for exercise.
        \task This is a simple text for exercise.
        \task This is a simple text for exercise.
        \task This is a simple text for exercise.
    \end{tasks}
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
    This is a simple text for exercise.
\end{exercise}

This is a simple text for exercise.This is a simple text before exercise.This is a simple text before exercise.This is a simple text before exercise.This is a simple text before exercise.

\begin{exercise}
    \begin{tasks}
        \task This is a simple text for exercise.
        \task This is a simple text for exercise.
        \task This is a simple text for exercise.
    \end{tasks}
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
    \begin{tasks}
        \task This is a simple text for exercise.
        \task This is a simple text for exercise.
        \task This is a simple text for exercise.
    \end{tasks}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

That's what it does

[image: MWE]

I don't like several things:

1. small vertical space before exercise 0.1
2. big vertical space between description of exercise 0.2 and its parts
3. small vertical space after exercise 0.2
4. alignment of parts of exercise 0.4 with empty description. Parts should start from the line with "Exercise 0.4" and all item labels should be equally shifted horizontally.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Outside of a list `\parskip` is zero, at least in your document setup. This is why `before-skip` and `after-skip` seem to have no effect. The space before and after an exercise is inyour control: add whatever amount suits you in your template definition of `main-task`, with `\vspace` or `\addvspace`. If your point 4. is at all possible reliably I'm not sure

Comment: Thanks. What can I do about exercises 0.4-0.5? They definitely should not look like this